# How do I paste into DOSBOX?

Tags: windows-8, copy-paste, dosbox

I am using [DOSBOX](http://www.dosbox.com/download.php?main=1) to run some programs which only work on 32-bit versions of Windows. I am currently running Windows 8 64-bit. I need to copy some commands from Windows 8 and paste them into DOSBOX as it would be very troublesome to type the entire command out.

I have searched the web but am unable to find anything on copying from Windows and pasting into DOSBOX. How do I do this?

Comment: Based on my research;  It doesn't support it.

Comment: I did install DosBox exactly because I needed to work faster in DOS. This sucks on so many levels ...

Answer (score 6):

If it's something that you can run every time you launch DOSBox, you could paste it into the DOSBOX configuration at the very end in the [autoexec] section:

```
[autoexec]
# Lines in this section will be run at startup.
# You can put your MOUNT lines here.
```

Comment: Of course, this will only work if what you're trying to paste is a DOS command.  Have you looked into creating a DOS batch file?

Comment: For those who are interested, running `DOSBox 0.74 Options.bat` will open up `dosbox-0.74.conf`

Answer (score 4):

There is already a solution for this by now. Try the latest enhanced DOSBox SVN build with mouse copy/paste and Long File Name (LFN) support. You can now use the right mouse button to select, copy and paste text from and to DOSBox (when the mouse is not locked).

Latest Windows binary + required DLLs, zipped: http://bit.ly/12jANWF

Related forum discussions & sources: http://www.vogons.org/viewtopic.php?f=41&t=41179

Comment: just for the record... what is the (or at least a) version after which copy paste is supported?

Answer (score 2):

If you use an older version of DosBox then you could create a .txt file from the host system which you later change to a .bat file. It should look like this:

```
mount c C:\Dosfiles\games
C:
```

Comment: Is the correct syntax of the mount command *mount **c:** C:\Dosfiles\games*?

Comment: @Twisty Yep, that works too. I just tested and it appears to work with or without the colon.

Answer (score 1):

DOSBox has no way to have text copied from the host system to it's self, it's emulates an entirely separate environment.

Answer (score 0):

very simple...(in case you are using it for writing a program)

To copy from DOSBox:

- write a program in DOSBox.
- save it
- open saved directory in file browser
- select the file and open with any text editor.

To copy into DOSBox:

- open your text file in text editor.
- save it in the dos box file directory with respected extension.
  (like `.c` or `.cpp` for languages.)
- open DOSBox
- Open the file in DOSBox

Answer (score 0):

Another option in case you're using an old DOSBox. Open Word or Excel. Press Alt-F11 to open the macro editor and then control+G to go to the debug window.

Enter:

```
S="<paste your text here>"
appactivate "DOSBox",true:for i=1 to len(S):sendkeys mid(s,i,1),true:t=timer:while(timer<t+.5):doevents:wend:next
```

I used the slowdown loop because the program I was trying to paste into couldn't keep up with `SendKeys`.